# Distinguish the clicked element in WPF routed event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in WPF I'm using a button with custom controltemplate.

My Button contains several sub elements like images.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myKey" TargetType="Button">
...
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
      <Image x:Name="img1"  />
       ...
      <Image x:Name="img2"  />
```

I've applied one Click-Handler to a button which uses the above template.

Now I want to know, which element in the visual tree of the button was clicked exactly. For example img1, img2, ...

Can I use the routed event arguments of the click event to distinguish the original element?

Thank you

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by using the `PreviewMouseDown` event (instead of the `Click` event) like

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource myKey}"
        PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown"
        Click="Button_Click"/>
```

You can get the image (if the click source was an image) using the `OriginalSource` of the event arguments. By combining this with the classic `Click` event you get the image of the click.

```
private Image buttonDownImage;

private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    buttonDownImage = e.OriginalSource as Image;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonDownImage != null)
    {
        //The click source the buttonDownImage
    }
}
```

The reason is the routing strategy, this means way the event is taking. Some more information about this routing strategies can be found at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx) or in this [WPF tutorial](https://wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html).

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. The PreviewMouseDown event contains as Original Source the image  - this works so far. But the PreviewMouseUp event doesn't contain the Image. Thus the user may click the sub-image on the button, move the mouse away, release the button and I would recognize this as "click" on my image. Is there any way to use the (bubbling)  click event directly?

Comment: I had the same idea. But this leads to a problem: When the user clicks, moves the mouse outside the button and releases outside of the button, the preview event fires but the click event doesn't. Thus "buttonDownImage" is not null the next time the user clicks the button - regardless if the second click is on the image or not. I didn't find any robust way to reset the global flag if the user releases the mouse button outside the clicked button

Comment: I thinkt thats not correct: Let's make an example: The click was abortet, buttonDownImage is not null. If the user clicks again (not at an image) `buttonDownImage = e.OriginalSource as Image;` sets to null (because the source is no image). This means the approach works.

Comment: oh.. You are absolute right. I think it's to warm in my office today ;) My original solution was a bit different from yours, therefore I didn't see how easy it really was. Little problem left: User clicks image, moves away from image but stays on the button -> Click occurs with state "image clicked". But thats okay for me -> solved. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think by using the `PreviewMouseUp` event to solve this little problem.

Comment: No as the e.OriginalSource   can't be casted into an Image in "up" event. Don't know why...